# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException as I try to convert hex string to byte array. Why do I get it?

Tags: java, cryptography

As I try to convert a `hex string` to a `byte array` I get this exception :

```
Aug 15, 2013 10:17:32 PM Tester main
SEVERE: null
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.BlowfishCipher.engineDoFinal(BlowfishCipher.java:319)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1978)
        at Tester.main(Tester.java:21)
```

Following is the code that attempted so :

```
try {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish");
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish"); 
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        String decryptSt = new String(cipher.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("f250d7a040859d66541e2ab4a83eb2225d4fff880f7d2506")));
        System.out.println(decryptSt);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

What is the problem ? Why am I getting an exception ?

Comment: This doesn't apply directly to this problem but to the chat that sparked this question. Remember that  calling `generateKey(` needs to be done before encryption and the key *saved* for decryption.

Comment: post full your code, nothing to do with this Exception. EDIt - nm

Comment: @MaximShoustin This is the complete code

Comment: Looking at your previous question, you should really study cryptography before you try to create implementations. If you are up to it, I would recommend the Coursera crypto course from Standford university/Dan Boneh...

Answer (score 1):

You can never decrypt with a random key. If you do, you will get plaintext consisting of random bytes. The cipher however tries to unpad the message. As it does not find a valid padding, you will get this exception. Note that - by "luck", about once in 256 - the padding may be correct, in which case you simply retrieve random bytes as plaintext.

Comment: What do I need to do to decrypt `f250d7a040859d66541e2ab4a83eb2225d4fff880f7d2506` when I know _blowfish_ algo has been used for encryption ?

Comment: Unless you also know the encryption key, you _cannot_ decrypt this.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Just perform a differental/impossibility attack on 31 of the 32 feistel rounds then bruteforce the rest. :P

Comment: @JimGarrison Hypothetical, the actual source known from a different question stores its keys in an accessible place.